# Azure Devops Pipeline stage progress via Rest API

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm trying to retrieve the progress (stages?) from a pipeline, from an Azure DevOps Project, via the Azure Rest API.
Several endpoints are already quite clear: retrieving projects within your organization, pipelines, the runs of each pipeline.
However, the actual progress of each run, in more detail which step / stage the pipeline run is, I cannot find.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/stages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0
only returns: in progress, but not the exact detail i'm looking for.[stages progress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Dyk.png)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/stages?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0

get me the progress of the stages, but unable to find

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [timeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) endpoint _apis/build/builds/{buildId}/timeline where the buildId is your pipeline run id aka build id.

The [TimelineRecord](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/timeline/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0#timelinerecord) provides you with very detailed information for example:

- type - will tell you whether the record is for a stage or task,
- name of the task/stage,
- the result code or status code,
- start and finish times,
- attempts,
- even the URIs to the log files produced by the steps etc.